# Convert string to int-objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, int

I haven't been able to figure out how to convert a NSString to an int. I'm trying to convert ASCII to text, but to do that I need to convert a string to an int.

I find it really strange that this isn't anywhere online or in stack overflow. I'm sure I'm not the online one who needs this.

Thanks in advance for helping.

P.S. If this helps here is the code I'm using to convert to ASCII:

```
+ (NSString *) decodeText:(NSString *)text {
    NSArray * asciiCode = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    int i = 0;
    NSMutableString *decoded;

    while (i < ([asciiCode count]-1) ) {

        NSString *toCode = [asciiCode objectAtIndex:i];
        int codeInt = toCode;
        NSString *decode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", codeInt];
        [decoded appendString:decode];

    }

    return decoded;
}
```

Comment: I looked at a lot of questions, but couldn't find an answer. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To parse string to integer you should do:

```
NSString *a = @"123abc";
NSInteger b = [a integerValue];
```

Comment: You can do that with an int as well. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps fractionally off-topic, but to convert to ASCII you could just use:

```
[NSString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]
```

Or in your example:

```
return [text dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
```

This will return an NSData which you could iterate through to obtain a string representation of ASCII (s per your method) if this is what you require.

The reason for using this approach is because NSString's can store non-ASCII characters, you will of course potentially lose detail, but enabling the allowLossyConversion flag will attempt to overcome this. As per [the Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/dataUsingEncoding%3aallowLossyConversion%3a):

> For example, in converting a character from NSUnicodeStringEncoding to
>   NSASCIIStringEncoding, the character ‘Á’ becomes ‘A’, losing the
>   accent.

Comment: so where do I add in the string I want to convert?

Comment: @DonyorM dataUsingEncoding... is a method you call *on* the string. (I'll update my answer.)

Comment: Thanks, sorry some functions start with "NSString" Mostly I'm a noob.